# reactjs - why don't select's get drawn immediately after rendering

Tags: reactjs

[Here is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-glade-ojfl9?file=/src/App.js) of a select that has an option added every second.

For some reason, the options don't appear every second but seemingly randomly. However, if you continually move your mouse the options *DO* appear every second. Seems like an event needs to be fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove select `size`, it works.

[See demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-dynamic-options-9hw9m)

Alternatively, you can render something using state, which will cause the options to appear each second.

```js
<div style={{ height: 0 }}>{this.state.parts.length}</div>  //hack
```

I am still looking into exact reason of why it is happening but above options will make your options appear as per your expectation.

Comment: Thanks for finding that out. Hopefully you'll find the root cause :)